# exams2pdf latex error !Missing $ inserted

Tags: r-exams

I am puzzled with this error when compiling an exercise with `exams2pdf()`:

```
Exam 1: ICvar (srt) ... w! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 ...rime 2}}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n-1)}}
                                                  ;\frac{(n-1)S^{\prime 2}}{...

Error: LaTeX failed to compile icvar1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See icvar1.log for more info.
```

This is the code from my `ICvar.Rmd` (I get the variables' values from previous code in the ICvar.rmd file link [here](https://ispaiu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jpmaroco_ispa_pt/EcTasUBV4c5MnoESs2D0nB8B2TWrcb3k-ns_piktxeq3vg?e=TfQewb) if you want to see the whole file):

```
Solution
========
Para $n$ = `r length(v)` um I.C. a `r cilevel*100`% para a $\sigma^2$ é:

$$\bigg] \frac{(n-1)S^{\prime 2}}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n-1)}};\frac{(n-1)S^{\prime 2}}{\chi^2_{\frac{\alpha}{2};(n-1)}}\bigg[$$
```

I am generating the latex file with:

```
exams2pdf(file="ICvar.Rmd",
          name = "icvar",
          engine="knitr",
          verbose=T
          )
```

And my latex (exercise01) file is:

```
\begin{question}
\textbf{Um intervalo de confiança a 99\% para variabilidade é:}
\begin{answerlist}
  \item {]}1599.909; 24699.887{[}{]}1225.75; 49863.356{[}{]}24.685;
235.649{[}{]}33.179; 227.154{[}{]}129.822; 130.511{[}{]}
\frac{(n-1)S^{\prime 2}}{\chi^2_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n-1)}};\frac{(n-1)S^{\prime 2}}{\chi^2_{\frac{\alpha}{2};(n-1)}}\bigg[$$

Assim:

$\bigg]\frac{(6-1) \times 64.079^2}{\chi_{1- \frac{0.01}{2};(6-1)}^2};\frac{(6-1) \times 64.079^2}{\chi_{\frac{0.01}{2};(6-1)}^2}
\bigg[ \iff$

$\bigg]\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{\chi_{1- 0.005;(5)}^2};\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{\chi_{0.005;(5)}^2}\bigg[ \iff$

$\bigg]\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{\chi_{0.995;(5)}^2};\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{\chi_{0.005;(5)}^2}\bigg[ \iff$

$\bigg]\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{16.75};\frac{5 \times 4106.118}{0.412}\bigg[ \iff$

$\bigg] 1225.736;49862.768\bigg{[}\$
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}
```

The `\end{answerlist}` is missing after the anwserlist, and no `\begin{solution} is present, and this causes the error, I believe. But can't figure out why tinytex is rendering the file as it is.

I am using:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22000)
other attached packages:
[1] tinytex_0.33 dplyr_1.0.7  exams_2.4-0
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated...
(by the way, the same file "knits" well within R studio and... exams2pdf() produces the pdf in Ubuntu 20).

Comment: I agree that the LaTeX file looks wrong, the `{question}` and `{solution}` seem to have been mixed up. However, I cannot replicate this. When I do `set.seed(1)` and `exams2pdf("ICvar.Rmd", texdir = "tmptex")` then the resulting file `tmptex/exercise1.tex` looks ok and not like the code you posted. Maybe something was edited by hand along the way?

Comment: Hi Achim. Thanks for the prompt answer. No, no editing ... and it works ok on a ubuntu server... Are you running a Win machine?

Comment: I'm on Debian. But at least it would not be obvious to me how the operating system could lead to the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

1. Unistall R 4.1
2. Unistall RStudio
3. Restart PC
4. Install R and Rstudio

And now it works...:-(

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! This solution suggests that there was something that corrupted the package, the output file, the output directory, etc. It is unlikely that this problem is reproducible for anyone - and the solution is not specific to the problem. Hence I would say: (a) Good that the problem is resolved on your end! (b) The question/answer can probably be deleted/hidden.

Comment: It would be great if we could close this question in some way. I would argue in favor of deleting it. But if you feel that your question and solution would be useful to someone else, please accept your own answer. _(Not sure whether you can already do so. Maybe you have to wait a couple of days more.)_